# Restrict internet access on work VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn

As I sometimes work from home, I have to connect to a VPN (made by Radmin VPN) in order to access my work's LAN for using JIRA server and other stuff as well. The thing is that if I want to do something else online while I work, I'm afraid it will go through the VPN instead of the default Wi-Fi adapter on my PC, and I don't want my boss to be able to see my private life... Is there a way to restrict traffic on the VPN to LAN and route everything else through Wi-Fi?

I'm using Windows 10 and Radmin VPN v1.1.3969.3 just to add some info. I'd think there is some way to achieve this via the "Network Connections" control panel page.

Comment: What your company can or cannot do actually entirely depends on the configuration of your VPN. It's best to keep work separate from private, the best way to do that, is to use a VM. Be sure you are connecting the VM to the VPN instead of the host, otherwise, you still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

A heavy solution is the old trick of running the VPN inside a virtual machine,
therefore not impacting the global Routing table. Below is detailed a solution
that uses the routing table with the
[route command](https://ss64.com/nt/route.html).

The following requirements must exist:

1. The VPN must allow [Split tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling)
2. The VPN must not change the default route in the
   [Routing table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table),
   or that default route must be reestablished after the connection to the VPN
3. You can communicate with the server on the VPN by using its IP address
   (the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) can help here).

**To configure Split Tunneling:**

First, modify the properties of the VPN connection to not be used as the default gateway for all traffic:

- Navigate to *Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings*
- Right click on the VPN connection, then choose Properties
- Select the Networking tab
- Select "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and click Properties"
- Click Advanced
- Deselect the box for "Use default gateway on remote network"
- Click OK to apply the changes to the interface
- Disable "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv6)"
- Click OK.

Next, add routes for the desired VPN subnets. This should be done with the VPN tunnel connected:

- Open a command prompt
- Run `ipconfig /all`
- In the list of interfaces, find the Description for the VPN connection created earlier. This will be needed later.
- Run the below command replacing the relevant information between the <> markings:

  ```
  netsh interface ipv4 add route <destination subnet> "<interface name>"
  ```

  For example, if "Home" is the name of your adapter and `192.168.128.0/24`
  the VPN network:

  ```
  netsh interface ipv4 192.168.128.0/24 "Home"
  ```

Comment: I think I've seen that option before. However, the network appears as a regular ethernet adapter (RadminVPN simulates one) and not as a VPN in the list, and the "Use default gateway on remote network" box does not appear. I know that is what makes the problem since I have another VPN configured as a regular one (and not through some software like Radmin) and the box does appear in that one's properties.