# VPN for some traffic and non-VPN for other traffic

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, routing

I use my work laptop only with WiFi, and when at home, I can use it to connect to my home network, which I do to play movies from my server in the basement, and I can RDP to that server.

However, when working, I have to connect to "Check Point Endpoint" to be on the corporate network, using the "Check Point Endpoint" VPN. As soon as I do this, all access to my local home network are no longer visible.

I have a USB WiFi adaptor, and I would like to plug that in and then use that adaptor exclusively to access my home network while the internal WiFi on the laptop routes all corporate network traffic.

Can anyone tell me how to do this please?

Note: I do not in any way want to *restrict* access on my work network. I want to be able to connect to my work network (bind the VPN to one adaptor say) and then plug in a USB WiFi adaptor which will allow me the ability to *additionally* see my local home network (just as I can do when the VPN is turned off).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict internet access on work VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/1526494/restrict-internet-access-on-work-vpn)

Comment: Unfortunately not. That question is about setting up a VPN inside a VM and all sorts. My laptop is a work laptop (corporate build). There is absolutely no possibility to turn that build into a VM. I have the laptop, and I then connect to VPN. The act of doing this cuts me off from my local home network. I would like a secondary network adapter (USB WiFI or USB ethernet, whatever) to continue to give me access to my home network. That other question is light years away from my scenario (really appreciate it all the same though, as that different scenario is interesting).

Comment: Edit the VPN settings, so it’s not the default gateway when connected. This way only trafic for your work lan will be routed through the vpn and all the other trafic will be routed through your own LAN. Then you don’t need an extra adapter.

Comment: The info in that answer applies here too.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://blog.lan-tech.ca/2013/02/21/access-local-and-vpn-network-simultaneously/

Comment: Thanks Harry / Gloria. I see in both that split-tunneling does appear to be the way to do this, and I also see that my corporate settings block me from doing this, so I think I have reached a dead end.  However, the links above will be very useful for anyone that happens by here I think as they are the answers.